# Multiple "On behalf of" email profiles

Tags: docusignapi

I have enterprise account and we are using it to send envelope signing requests via email to our users. Currently it shows "From" in email as `"XYZ Ltd via DocuSign"`. As we have multiple brand profiles, I want this "From" to be displayed as per brand(like `"LineOfBusiness1 via DocuSign"`) - Using same integrator key though. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

[image: Screenshot in Microsoft Outlook]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We resolved it as below.

1. We have created 4 different users each for 1 brand.
2. Now while sending request to docusign api for creating envelope- we are using brand specific email in authentication.
   Name corresponding to this email will come after "via" in email.
3. This solution allows us to use sme integration key - and we can easily change/add/delete brand by adding/modifying users.